# dart to java convert . or combine java code with dart flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I have a app which is built in flutter dart language. Now I  want to add  some more features using java.
 Is this possible to add java coded features in dart . Can I combine java code with dart flutter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider reviewing our suggested reading for [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you explain your problem that you are trying to solve by doing things as you mentioned in question?

Comment: Is there any solution? Convert dart to java

Answer (score 3):

Flutter apps are written in Dart which are compiled to native code for the platform (Android or iOS) it is deployed on.

Java code is compiled to bytecode that must be executed on a Java Virtual Machine. There is no JVM for iOS so you're out of luck there. Android has the Android Runtime -- code written for Android in the Java language is compiled to Java byte code first, then translated to the Android Runtime format.

So what you want isn't possible on iOS but could be possible in Android. If it is possible, then you would have a Flutter app that could only run on Android, which at least partially (if not completely) removes the main reasons for using Flutter/Dart in the first place. If targeting only Android, just write the entire app in Java or Kotlin.